# Css property not reflected for bootstrap specific button tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/
   3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
   </script>
    <script 
  src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Button Group</h2>
  <p>The .btn-group class creates a button group:</p>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Samsung</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sony</button>
  </div>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
button{
background-color:red;
}
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above segment, Bootstrap is being used and when tried to apply the background-color property for the button tag,it is not being reflected.What is the reason for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add !important:

```
<style type="text/css">
button{
background-color: red !important;
}
</style>
```

Or put your <style> upper, than your divs and buttons... sometimes that is the issue.

Comment: Working beautifully.what does "! important signify"?

Comment: Avoid <style> tags in code please, just import a custom .css file :)

Comment: You can add this everywhere in CSS... it means "Ignore CSS code from another sources, this code is more important"

Comment: Instead of using !important a good advise is to create new classes - you can copy bootstrap styles for current classes- and use it in your tags instead of boostraps'

Answer (score 1):

**You can use `!important`**, **because bootstrap already written a styl**e. So if you want to overwrite that style, maybe you will need to write it down under the bootstrap's style, otherwise you will need to add `!important`.

***I think this website will help you to understand the reason of `!important`***.
https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/